# Parsing PDF date using Java DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date, datetime, pdf, datetime-format

I'm trying to parse the date format used in PDFs. According to [this page](https://www.verypdf.com/pdfinfoeditor/pdf-date-format.htm), the format looks as follows:

```
D:YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHH'mm'
```

Where all components except the year are optional. I assume this means the string can be cut off at any point as i.e. specifying a year and an hour without specifying a month and a day seems kind of pointless to me. Also, it would make parsing pretty much impossible.

As far as I can tell, Java does not support zone offsets containing single quotes. Therefore, the first step would be to get rid of those:

```
D:YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHHmm
```

The resulting Java date pattern should then look like this:

```
['D:']uuuu[MM[dd[HH[mm[ss[X]]]]]]
```

And my overall code looks like this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("['D:']uuuu[MM[dd[HH[mm[ss[X]]]]]]");
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest("D:20020101",
    ZonedDateTime::from,
    LocalDateTime::from,
    LocalDate::from,
    Month::from,
    Year::from
);
```

I would expect that to result in a LocalDate object but what I get is `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'D:20020101' could not be parsed at index 2`.

I've played around a bit with that and found out that everything works fine with the optional literal at the beginning but as soon as I add optional date components, I get an exception.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I put my suggestion here: https://rextester.com/OQF29673. It’s longer but also more explicit and doesn’t use the `p` format pattern letter because it’s really for space padding, not zero padding, so I considered it an unpleasant hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```java
String dateString = "D:20020101120000+01'00'";
String normalized = dateString.replace("'", "");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("['D:']ppppy[ppM[ppd[ppH[ppm[pps[X]]]]]]");
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest(normalized,
    OffsetDateTime::from,
    LocalDateTime::from,
    LocalDate::from,
    YearMonth::from,
    Year::from
);
```

As it seems, the length of the components is ambiguous and parsing of the date without any separators thus failed.
When specifying a padding, the length of each component is clearly stated and the date can therefore be parsed.

At least that's my theory.

Comment: Good find! However, you still need to make two changes for this to work for the full format: (1) `dateTimeString = dateTimeString.replaceAll("'(\\d{2})'$", ":$1");`. There can be other alternatives but this is an easy option. (2) Use  `XXX` in the pattern i.e. use the pattern `"['D:']ppppy[ppM[ppd[ppH[ppm[pps[XXX]]]]]]"`.

Comment: Yes, single quotes have to be removed. I'll update the answer. However, I'd rather use `replaceAll("'", "")` in order to allow for missing offset minutes. Parsing the whole string works for me using `X`. And I think for formatting, accoding to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html you would have to use `XX` to get the same format (minus the single quotes).

Comment: Prefer `YearMonth` over `Month` when we know a year must be present. Also prefer `OffsetDateTime` over `ZonedDateTime` when you may have an offset but certainly no time zone . A single quote, `'`, can be parsed when you place two of them in the pattern, `''`. I find this nicer than the manual removal.

Comment: Please forget what I said about the apostrophe.  It doesn't work within a UTC offset.